# XCode: Graphical button with invisible title

Tags: xcode, button, title, invisible

I have a bunch of buttons. They appears as an graphical image. If a user clicked on a button I can determine with

sender.titleLabel!.text!

which button the user pressed. But the title of the button appears in the view. I want only to show the image and give the button a invisible title. But I think that is not possible.

Me second solution is to create for each button an outlet. But I think with 30 buttons that is a very bad solution.

Comment: Solution 1: Shrink the button, so the label with the title disappears. Solution 2: Set font size to "1" so the label disappears.

Comment: There's really no reason to set a title if it's not going to be visible. If you need to distinguish between several different buttons (that all trigger the same action, for example), use the `tag` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

For the button text color property set opacity to 0. The text is there, but fully transparent.

**Option 2:**

You may use the tag value to identify a button so you do not have to rely on the button title. You can set the tag value in interface builder (Xcode) or in code. (The tag is an integer.)

I usually prefer option 2 as it is resilient to text changes over time (think of typos, translations for other languages etc.).